# Loading from file sring and float in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have data:

```
A 5.6
F 4.2 
D 45.5 
A 8.45
```

I tried this three code, where file is file the data above and xfile and yfile only one of the column.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.genfromtxt('xfile',dtype='str')
y = np.loadtxt('yfile', unpack=True, usecols=[0])
print(x)
print(y)



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('xfile', 'r') as file:
    x = file.read().replace('\n', '')
y = np.loadtxt('yfile', unpack=True, usecols=[0])
print(x)
print(y)





import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('file', 'r') as file:
    x = file.read().replace('\n', '')
y = np.loadtxt('file', unpack=True, usecols=[1])
print(x)
print(y)
```

In the third script there is a problem that I don't know how to load only the first column. In the first and second code, there is a problem with data type.

Error:

```
    return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'CA'
```

Comment: What is extension of these files, is it `.txt` or something else

Comment: I used no extension, it that problem?

Comment: Yes, it can be. I have created two file with `xfile.txt` and `yfile.txt` and used your code and it worked. But changed some part of it. I will post code in answer. Try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code, Hope it will help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.genfromtxt('xfile.txt',dtype='str')
y = np.loadtxt('yfile.txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0])
print(x)
print(y)



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('xfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    x = file.read().replace('\n', '')
y = np.loadtxt('yfile.txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0])
print(x)
print(y)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('xfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    x = file.read().replace('\n', '')
y = np.loadtxt('yfile.txt', unpack=True)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Hope this helps :)